# Merge row in mysql which has different values in some columns

Tags: mysql, merge, row

I have records in my table as follows:

[image]

and I want a result like follows:

![enter image description here][2]

how can do that in MYSQL

Comment: Please don't post images for sample data instead include sample data in textual format or better to use any online tool, Also include your complete table definitions and expected output

Comment: What you have tried?